# Preventing video pause when headset is removed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudiosession, headset

**Language Used**: Swift 2.3

I am using `AVPlayerViewController` and here's my code

```
let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoUrl!)            
playerViewController.player = player
playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = false
```

What I'm doing here is I'm playing a Video that is supposed to be unpausable and unskippable.

Here I'm monitoring if the video has ended using `NSNotificationCenter`

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.actionAfterVideo), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: nil)
```

Which would then dismiss my `AVPlayerViewController`

```
func actionAfterVideo() {
    playerViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

All of these works perfectly fine except when a **user** plugs and unplugs a headset. This automatically pauses the video. They could resume it of course by using the `Control Center` but that wouldn''t be intuitive.

Is there anyway I could prevent the video from pausing when a headset is unplugged from the phone?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a notification to check if session has been interrupted like this :

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playInterrupt:", name: AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification, object: yourSession)
```

And add its `playInterrupt` implementation like this :

```
func playInterrupt(notification: NSNotification)
{
    if notification.name == AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification && notification.userInfo != nil
    {
        var info = notification.userInfo!
        var intValue: UInt = 0

        (info[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as! NSValue).getValue(&intValue)

        if let type = AVAudioSessionInterruptionType(rawValue: intValue)
        {
            switch type
            {
            case .Began:
                player.pause()
            case .Ended:
                let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: "resumeNow:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            }
        }
    }
}

func resumeNow(timer : NSTimer)
{
    player.play()
    print("restart")
}
```

Also have a look at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html)

Comment: Is there way todo the same with web audio. Its pauses videos, which are run within a wkwebview. I guess I could inject a js which looks up all paused video tags and call play on them.